# Where to find GPS data received over TCP?

Tags: php, gps, portforwarding

I have done all the port forwarding and the rest settings on the server. Now I am confused about, where to find gps data received and how to process it to save on the data base.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide details on what you have done so far. You question is a bit vague. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What is your Setup ?
GPS Data are Not Part of a Default TCP Packet